# Как связать элементы Listbox и элементы массива экземпляров класса?

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, классы, listbox

Есть массив из 5 экземпляров класса человек,у каждого по свойству - имя.
В Listbox поочередно записываются все имена всех экземпляров класса человек.
Получается так,что индексы Listbox и индексы массива с "человеками" совпадают.
Получается что элемент Listbox с индексом 0 будет хранить имя "Вася",и элемент массива "человеков" с индексом 0 будет иметь имя такое же имя - "Вася".
Но если отсортировать содержимое Listbox, то получится, что один и тот же индекс будет ссылаться на одно имя в LIstbox и на другое в массиве.
Как можно не нарушить связь между элементами Listbox и массива? 
Другими словами как связать элементы Listbox  и элементы массива экземпляров класса?

Comment: Храните целиком объекты и при сортировке меняйте местами их целиком. Связные списки вам в помощь.

Comment: Как можно хранить их вместе?

Comment: @Denis я бы приложил,да кода в проекте ну уж очень много.Прмер, описанный выше это простейшее описание проблемы,с которой я столкнулся

Comment: Вы хотя бы напишите, откуда у вас `ListBox` - WPF или WinForms? И покажите код, как данные попадают в листбокс.

Comment: @Alexander WinForms,данные в ListBox попадают посредством цикла foreach,в котором перебираются все элементы массива и записываются поочерёдно с помощью ListBox.Items.Add( );